# Program for getting amount of words that start with Vowels and Consenants is returning wrong answers

Tags: c++

Im writing a program for class and so far i have the word counter working fine and the vowel part working fine but Consonants and non alpha digits return wrong answers by 1(in certain cases). i think the problem lies in the testing of the characters them selves but i cant seem to find a way around it.

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    char ch;
    int count = 0;
    int vowel = 0;
    int cons = 0;
    int noalph = 0;

    bool inword = 1;
    bool space = 0;

    while (cin.get(ch)) {
        if (ch != ' ') {
            inword = 1;
        }
        if (isspace(ch)) {
            space = 1;
        }
        else if (space && inword) {
            count++;
            space = 0;
            inword = 0;

            if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u' || 
                ch == 'A' || ch == 'E' || ch == 'I' || ch == 'O' || ch == 'U' || 
                ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y') {
                vowel++;
            }

            if (ch != 'a' && ch != 'e' && ch != 'i' && ch != 'o' && ch != 'u' && 
                ch != 'A' && ch != 'E' && ch != 'I' && ch != 'O' && ch != 'U' && 
                ch != 'y' && ch != 'Y'
                && isalpha(ch)) {
                cons++;
            }

            if (ispunct(ch) || isdigit(ch)) {
                noalph++;
            }
        }
    }

    if (count > 0) {
        count++;
    }
    //--------------------------------------------

    cout << "Total Number of Words = " << count << endl;
    cout << "Number of Words Beginning with a Vowel = " << vowel << endl;
    cout << "Number of Words Beginning with a Consonant = " << cons << endl;
    cout << "Number of Words Beginning with a Non-Alpha = " << noalph << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Example 1(
Input:--------------------------------------------------------------------

supercalifragilisticexpialidocious
A nonsense-word used esp. by children, now chiefly expressing excited
approbation: fantastic, fabulous.
  Made popular by the Walt Disney film "Mary Poppins" in 1964. The
song containing the word was the subject of a copyright infringement
suit brought in 1965 against the makers of the film by Life Music
Co. and two song-writers: cf. quots. 1949, 1951. In view of earlier
oral uses of the word sworn to in affidavits and dissimilarity between
the songs the judge ruled against the plaintiffs.

Taken from the OED.

Output:--------------------------------------------------------------------

Total Number of Words = 86

Number of Words Beginning with a Vowel = 25

Number of Words Beginning with a Consonant = 55

Number of Words Beginning with a Non-Alpha = 5

Expected:------------------------------------------------------------------

Total Number of Words = 86

Number of Words Beginning with a Vowel = 25

Number of Words Beginning with a Consonant = 56

Number of Words Beginning with a Non-Alpha = 5

)

Example 2(
Input:--------------------------------------------------------------------

1996
bottle
12345
radar
a Toyota
Madam, I'm Adam
Was it a rat I saw?
Norma is as selfless as I am, Ron.
A man, a plan, a canal--Panama!
Tarzan raised Desi Arnaz' rat.
Hannah
Lewd did I live, & evil I did dwel.
Excerpts from "The Zen of Programming"
Mary said, "I like the STL."

Output:--------------------------------------------------------------------

Total Number of Words = 56

Number of Words Beginning with a Vowel = 20

Number of Words Beginning with a Consonant = 31

Number of Words Beginning with a Non-Alpha = 4

Expected:------------------------------------------------------------------

Total Number of Words = 56

Number of Words Beginning with a Vowel = 20

Number of Words Beginning with a Consonant = 31

Number of Words Beginning with a Non-Alpha = 5

)

As you can see it breaks at different points, maybe its something simple maybe it not, i would just like some help understanding what is going on, Thank You!

Comment: Have you tried (much much much) smaller things? What about just "cat" or "angry cat" and the likes, to see if it becomes more obvious. Try to make the input much smaller

Comment: no but but dont forget the inputs are set and cant be changed so i have to write for those inputs @Tas

Comment: When you are debugging its better to start with a small example.

Comment: I literally googled if `Y` is considered a vowel or not ? I never knew. But in your case you consider it purely as a vowel.

Comment: actually since this program tests only the first character vowels and y is always a vowel if it is the first character, so yes its a always a vowel in my case, this program only tests for vowels and the other items at the beginning of a word and nowhere else. @aep

Comment: Have you tried a short input yet?  I believe you will find something very interesting by taking the advice given by Tas.

Comment: So in the word "yellow" that "y" is a vowel?

Comment: According to google, yes. @DavidSchwartz

Comment: Then you're using a different google than I am. From my first several hits: **FIrst:** "The letter Y is a consonant sound when it is at the beginning of a word (yes) or is the first letter in the syllable before a vowel (beyond = be/yond). Vowel: The letter Y is a vowel sound when it is at the end of a word (happy) or anywhere else in the syllable (gym, crying)." **Next:** "Typically, the letter “y” is a consonant when it is at the beginning of a word, e.g., yes, ..." **Next:** "The "y" at the beginning of a word usually sounds like a consonant, which is what it is, .." And on and on and on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, you didn't followed advices in comments, so let do it explicitly.
You are skipping the first word.
Cause of the initialization in this line:

```
bool space = 0;
```

you should initialize it as true

```
bool space = true;
```

(yes, use `true` and `false` for boolean).

you should see that cause you added this lines

```
if (count > 0) {
    count++;
}
```

to cover this problem. So, remove them.

You also skipped the `#include <iostream>` directive.

Comment: alright so i just ran the code, It Worked! but i did try smaller inputs right before bed to attempt to isolate the error but i never saw anything off on the smaller outputs, Maybe i was just tired. But thanks for the help. @everyone